# How to properly compress single image videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that I am converting through an automated system that is 7mb, it is basically an mp3 with an image.

Now when its converted it magically becomes 17mb. My guess is its looping through the images instead of compressing them. The video was downloaded from youtube.

Here is my command that I'm converting it with:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  -i '/home/site/www-video/Upload/Temp/9d40b683eb2e8e8a036d64c741d04e01.flv' -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -vpre fast_firstpass  -s 480x360   -g 12   -fs 524288000   -vsync 2  -threads 0 -f rawvideo -an -y /dev/null
&& 
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  -i '/home/site/www-video/Upload/Temp/9d40b683eb2e8e8a036d64c741d04e01.flv'  -pass 2  -acodec copy  -vcodec libx264 -vpre fast -b 512k  -g 12   -s 480x360   -fs 524288000   -vsync 2  -threads 0 -y /home/site/www-video/Upload/Temp/15616/video.flv
```

As you can see I'm converting it to the same format and it magically gains 10mb

Comment: I also tried mencoder, that compresses the video properly but it has stuttering problems with normal videos and I cannot inject metadata to it (yamdi fails with no error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, ffmpeg was increasing the bitrate and I had to write some code in php to get the video's bitrate if it was lower than 512k and set the output bitrate to it.